# Correct location on device, but not on emulator (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, location

As title says, I use  Google Maps on my App, but the thing is, when I run my App on my phone (LG G4) It shows my current location, but when I try to run it on an emulator (Android Studio integrated emulator) it shows Google's Offices location
I've already checked if my computer has its location located there, but no, everything seems fine excepting that.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in emulator's extended controls. Click the three dots on the emulator side button panel and the first settings page is where you set the GPS coordinates you want to emulate.

Comment: Even after doing this, I continue to get 37.4219506, -122.0839954 (Google Plex coordinates in California)